# Changing my rear wheel tyre from 26 x 2.1 to 26 x 2.0: what's the difference?

Tags: tire, rear-wheel, tyre-width

Firstly, would a 26 x 2.0 tyre fit, and would there be a noticeable difference compared to my original tyre? (I am going from 2.10 to 2.0)

Comment: From 2.1 to 2.0 there will be no noticeable difference. That is only a change of 2.54 millimeters of width. Also not all listed tire sizes are perfectly accurate so you may have no difference at all.

Answer (score 2):

I am reasonably assured the larger tire will fit. As has been stated here before, bicycle tire width sizes aren't an exact standard. Maker A's tire size 2.0 inch may in fact be larger than Maker B's 2.1. The best information comes from user reviews about a specific model. Just to be sure look at your current tire. Does it barely fit between the frame stays? When on the smallest front sprocket how close is the front derailleur from hitting the tire. If the tolerances are very close the larger tire may not fit. Tire design also comes into play. A full knobby tire ( WTB velociraptor)  may hit while a microknob  (Geax AKA) may have enough clearance.

Comment: he is going from 2.1 -> 2.0 in my understanding

Comment: That is my point you have no way of knowing if a different  brand, type or size is physically larger or smaller than the original.

Comment: I'm tempted to change "I am reasonably assured the larger tire will fit" to "I am reasonably assured a similar-sized tire will fit" and that while 2.0 is nominally 5% smaller, it could end up slightly wider than a 2.1 because of manufacturer tolerances.

Comment: That is from where my comment arose, as the larger marked tire is already on the bike so yes it will fit..

Comment: Again my point is just because one tire is sized 2.0 inches, it is not  a given fact that it will be smaller than a different brand or tread type  sized 2.1 inches. There is no standard for width specifications, it is what the manufacturer  decides  to call it.